# How do I install plugins for WordPress?

Tags: 14.04, plugins, wordpress

I've installed WordPress by the Software Centre, now what I'm interested in doing is adding plugins and the codex centre (http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins) tells me that I should see a plugins option in the panel to the left-hand side of WordPress that, for some reason, I don't see. Here's my screenshot and here's what I'm told I'm meant to see (from this website).

What I see
[image: What I see]

What I'm meant to be [seeing](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:plugins.png).

Comment: How it is related to ubuntu? Looks like issue with the wordpress. Anyway you can have a look here - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/missing-plugin-tab

Comment: I thought it could be relevant as I've looked everywhere, including where your link told me to look, and I can't find it. Hence, as it seems I'm the only experiencing this trouble it could be related to me using Ubuntu as most WordPress users use either Mac or Windows.

Comment: Nvm I found the answer; I was using WordPress.com which is the only one available in the software centre I should be using the WordPress.org as it's the one with plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install **Simple**, **Shibboleth** and **Openid** plugins by:

```
sudo apt-get install wordpress-xrds-simple wordpress-shibboleth wordpress-openid
```

Answer (score 0):

First be sure you are an admin and not a lower level user on the blog itself. This will give you access to the plugins section in the dashboard.

You could also install the plug-in files directly into the plugins folder via FTP.

```
/blogfolder/wp-content/plugins
```